# How do I generate dynamic form from custom field post type in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7, trellis

I'm currently doing a project using Trellis/Wordpress/Sage stack. I also use a couple of plugins: "**Advanced custom fields**", "**Custom post type UI**", "**Contact form 7**" and an extension of Contact Form 7 called Contact form 7 dynamic text extension.

I have created a post type called Position, each position has description - text field, type - text field, and questions - repeater field, each subfield in questions is a text field named "question".

The user story in the design requires a multi-step form. In the first page, the user has to tick some check boxes - which are the questions from Position post type. Then the data will get carried over to the next form - the application form.

I'm having trouble with querying the subfields from Position posts and put their values in checkboxes, I can do it in plain php template file using `get_field()` and `get_subfield()` but I'm not sure how to pass them to another template in which the application form resides. I can provide further codes if required.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar and created a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/) that allows mapping between cf7 forms and custom post types.  So when your form is submitted, it is saved to its mapped post.  The plugin has several hooks built-in for you to manipulate the submitted data.  Moreover, once a form is submitted you can easily pre-fill the next form by creating a draft post to which the next form is mapped to, with the values from the first submission and redirect the page to the next form. The user will then see the next form with some  fields pre-filled with values their entered in the previous form.

If this looks promising, let me know by selecting this as you answer and I will give you a few more pointers as to how to proceed.